# What was the first movie where a recognizable newscaster played himself / herself?

Tags: character, first-appearance, cameo

Newscasters occasionally appear as themselves in movies, and recite fictitious news to move the movie's story along. For example, Matt Lauer has appeared as himself recently in both Zoolander 2 and Entourage. What is the first movie where a recognizable newscaster / journalist did this?

Comment: If you allow radio, John Snagge on the Goon Show in about 1958.

Answer (score 5):

Earliest I can think is of is BBC news reader Kenneth Kendall reading the news in 2001: A Space Odyssey in 1968:

[image]

Comment: I think @BrettFromLA was asking for an anchor/reporter playing himself.   I cannot remember this scene in the movie.  Do you know if Kendall was billed as "Himself" or something more generic like "News Anchor" in the credits?

Comment: It's uncredited, but he was active in news until his death in (real) 2012 so he could be playing himself, also he was a household face/name at the time so anyone from the UK would have said "there's Kenneth Kendall"

Comment: That's a good answer! It's borderline though, because he was uncredited.  We'd need to ask Stanley Kubrick his intentions, but that's not an option. (Upvote anyway!)

Comment: Thanks, I won't also mention the iPad he's on in 1968 

Comment: In 1960's movies Sink the Bismark, Edward R. Morrow played himself as a newscaster who was in London in 1941.

Comment: "Earliest I can think", YMMV as they say.